# What happens during the process of cin.get()?

Tags: c++, cin

The code is as follows, when I enter "101010^Z000", my output becomes "000". Obviously, my input is invalid after it becomes "^Z". However, why can I continue typing after typing "^Z"? According to the code, shouldn't it have jumped out of the loop and ended the program at this time? I'm curious.

```
int main()
{
 const int num = 20;
 int a[num];
 int i = 0;
 while((a[i]=cin.get())!=EOF)
  {
    a[i] = cin.get();
    cout.put(a[i]);
    i++;
  }
 cout << a;
}
```

like this:

[image]

And, after this I keep typing "ssss" and the program still outputs "ss" as if the loop is continuing.
[image]

Comment: Why are you doing another `a[i] = cin.get();` inside the loop? That will overwrite the character you read on the line above, `while((a[i]=cin.get())!=EOF)`

Comment: Also, try pressing `ctrl-z` after pressing the `return` key.

Comment: And `cout << a;` doesn't print the whole array if that's what you hope for.

Comment: Also ctrl-z may cause EOF on Windows but might not on Linux. Traditionally it's Ctrl-D there. Ctrl-Z is end of transmission,It works only if buffer is fully flushed (return entered before it). This is legacy behaviour and shouldn't be used to check for end of file, `cin` got a member function for it. EOF is -1 (255) and no input character may be equal to it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Input is usually *buffered*. There is nothing in C++ that says it must be buffered but usually it is. What this means is that when your program is waiting for input it waits for a whole line of input. That whole line of input goes into a *buffer* and subsequent reads take characters from the buffer until it is empty. Then the next read will cause the program to wait again, and again it will wait for a whole line of input to be entered.

If you want unbuffered input then I've afraid there is no way to get that in standard C++. You have to use platform specific functions for that.

Comment: I'm curious why there is still an input stream entering the buffer after typing "^Z"?

Comment: Again this has nothing to do with C++. It's the console that controls the buffer, and the console knows nothing about ^Z, for the console ^Z is just another character. In my experience with Windows if you want to use ^Z as the end of file, then you should type it as the first and only character on a line.